# How to add empty png block to image?

Tags: linux, shell

I have some images:

```
1.png (10x10px)
2.png (15x20px)
3.png (20x20px)
```

I need to make the same size for all images (for larger size).
Smaller images should be centered.
How I can do that?

Comment: And how big should they all become when you are finished - 10x10, 20x20, 32x32? And when images are larger than the output size, should they be cropped or decreased in size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ImageMagick` library,

```
convert input.png -background transparent -gravity center -extent 8x8 output.png
```

where 8x8 is the size of output.png. If the original image is bigger, it's cropped, otherwise, the original image is centered over a transparent background.

**Original image (32x32)**

[image: Original image (32x32)]

**image after using command with** *-extent 8x8*

[image: image after using command with -extent 8x8]

**image after using command with** *-extent 200x200*

[image: image after using command with -extent 200x200]